# how to get different cell groups each add up to a certain number

Tags: excel, solver

I have an excel file that has one column which contains numbers that represent file sizes, each of those numbers is a floating point number with a max decimal places of two (Ex: 23.04). the total cells count is (277 cells).i want to automatically group cells that add up to (**1000**) or **as close as possible** to that number (1000). the sum of all the cells is (5739.49) so, ***there should be (4) groups of cells***, each adds up to (1000) and the ***last one (5th group) doesn't matter*** how much it adds up to. now :

- I know that this can be solved using "**THE SOLVER**" in excel for each group But i'm
  not sure what constraints i should use and which solving method (i.e, the simplex, GRG nonlinear or the evolutionary) methods because i'm not familiar with it

thank You in advance

Comment: Standard Solver in Excel has a [maximum limit for decision variables](http://www.solver.com/standard-excel-solver-dealing-problem-size-limits) of 200. Your problem has 277 (which group does each cell belong to).

Comment: I know that, we can take the 1st 200 values first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the standard solver in Excel has a maximum limit for decision variables of 200.

This example is limited to 200 variables - if you have the premium solver, you can expand the solution. This was done using Excel 2016.

**Worksheet setup**

1. Column A contains the size data.
2. Column B contains the "Group" that each member in Column A will belong to. It is initially populated using the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(1,5)`. It was then overridden using Copy / Paste Special - Values.
3. Column D contains the aggregated groups, labelled 1 through 5.
4. Column E contains the aggregated size within each group. It is calculated with `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$201,"="&D2,$A$2:$A$201)`
5. Column F contains the target value for each group (1000 for groups 1 through 4, ignored for group 5).
6. Column G contains the squared error from the target value for each group. It is calculated with `=(E2-F2)^2`
7. Cell G7 will be the "Set Objective" cell and is the sum of error squared. It is calculated with `=SUM(G2:G5)`

Below is a screen shot of the setup worksheet, before using solver.

[image]

**Solver Setup**

Solver is setup with the following criteria ...

1. "Set Objective:" is `$G$7`
2. "To:" is "Min"
3. "By Changing Variable Cells:" is `$B$2:$B$201`
4. "Subject to the Constraints:" includes: `$B$2:$B$201 <= 5`, `$B$2:$B$201 = integer`, and `$B$2:$B$201 >= 1`
5. "Select a Solving Method:" is `Evolutionary`. Note: You could use GRG, but it will be much slower.
6. In "Options", on the "All Methods" tab, in the "Solving with Integer Constraints" area, make sure `Ignore Integer Constraints` is *not* checked.

Below is a screen shot of the Solver Parameters dialog:

[image]

**Solution**

Your optimal region may be "flat" so there are multiple possible solutions.

Below is a screen shot of a solution I generated ...

[image]

Comment: i appreciate your effort and taking the time to answer me, i will definitely try that...good idea how you used the concept of minimization which is kinda like that in neural networks

Comment: how did you arrange which value in column A belongs to which group in column B?

Comment: i tried your solution on another example where i used the error function  to be the absolute value of the difference i.e ABS(E-F) because my my initial errors were ranging from negative to positive and also their values was considerable

Comment: Error squared removes the sign, similar to absolute value.

Comment: Initial values for column B were randomly selected using the RANDBETWEEN function, as described in the post.