# Create groups of 24 using Solver

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, solver

I have a list of 60 schools in range A2:A61.
In Column B, I have a # of Students for each of the schools in A.

I want classes of 24, not splitting up students from the same school.
I'm trying to create groups of 24 using Solver.

In Column C, I have a column of 0s
In Column D, I have the product of Column B * Column C
In D62, I have the total of D2:D61.

I use Solver to try to make D62 = 24 while changing the 0s in Column C, with the constraint that the values of Column C must be binary.

```vb
Sub Grouping()

Dim setCellRange As Range, valueofRange As Range, byChangeRange As Range

Set setCellRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D62")
Set valueofRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B63")
Set byChangeRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C61")

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 3
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=setCellRange.Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=valueofRange.Address, ByChange:=byChangeRange.Address, _
      Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=byChangeRange.Address, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverOk SetCell:=setCellRange.Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=valueofRange.Address, ByChange:=byChangeRange.Address, _
      Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=setCellRange.Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=valueofRange.Address, ByChange:=byChangeRange.Address, _
      Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

    Set setCellRange = setCellRange.Cells(1, 4)
    Set valueofRange = valueofRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set byChangeRange = byChangeRange.Cells(1, 4)

    Cells(1, i * 3 + 2).Value = "# of Students"
    Cells(2, i * 3 + 2).Value = "=RC[-3]-RC[-1]"
    Cells(2, i * 3 + 2).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, i * 3 + 2), Cells(61, i * 3 + 2))
    Range(Cells(2, i * 3 + 2), Cells(61, i * 3 + 2)).Select
    Cells(1, i * 3 + 3).Value = "Binary"
    Cells(2, i * 3 + 3).Value = "0"
    Cells(2, i * 3 + 3).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, i * 3 + 3), Cells(61, i * 3 + 3))
    Range(Cells(2, i * 3 + 3), Cells(61, i * 3 + 3)).Select
    Cells(1, i * 3 + 4).Value = "Product"
    Cells(2, i * 3 + 4).Value = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
    Cells(2, i * 3 + 4).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, i * 3 + 4), Cells(61, i * 3 + 4))
    Range(Cells(2, i * 3 + 4), Cells(61, i * 3 + 4)).Select
    Cells(62, i * 3 + 4).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-60]C:R[-1]C)"

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I know macro recording puts in two instances of SolverOK, but you only need one. Also, do not specify both `Engine` and `EngineDesc` - only specify one of them.

Comment: I am not sure you need VBA for this problem. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196466/how-to-get-different-cell-groups-each-add-up-to-a-certain-number/40311438#40311438) of grouping data using solver..